# Return value from DataGridView and pass it to another class

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, datagridview

I have following problem:
I use a Form where I have a DataGridView to show SQL tables. Now, after I wrote some functions I wanted to make another class for a search function. Everything (Textboxes etc) can be passed now and I can call the function in the class from my form with (for example)

```
sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [CURRENT_DEMAND] WHERE
[Product_No] LIKE '" + form1.filterType().Trim() + "%'", connection);
```

So I did the following: I created a new object from my class in Form1

```
 dbSearch = new DB_Search(this);
        dbSearch.filterDB();
```

then I did the following in my class:

```
 public Form1 form1 = null;
 public DB_Search(Form1 frm1)
    {
        form1 = frm1;
    }
```

after that I wanted to call a Textbox which is located in my Form, so I wrote a function in my Form:

```
 public String filterType()
    {
        return filterTypeNumber.Text;
    }
```

and finally I could take the value from the Textbox because I changed

```
form1.filterTypeNumber.Text
```

to

```
form1.filterType()
```

In my class. now I need to modify the last line

```
        datTable = new DataTable();
        sqlDatAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd.CommandText,
        connection);
        sqlDatAdapter.Fill(datTable);
form1.dataGridView1.DataSource = datTable;
```

so I need a function in my form that takes the DataGridView value which I can call in my class but how to do that? Or better said I need to take the DataGridView value from my form to set it to datTable.

Comment: Do you need to pass a value "from" the DataGridView "to the filterType" method?

Comment: The DataGridView.DataSource value is in Form1. I want to take that value and pass it to the class where I can take the value and set it to datTable like above with dataGridView1.Datasource = datTable

Comment: I think it's better to edit your question and expand your sample code so every can see it and better understand what you want to achieve. Put in as many comments as possible in the code.

Comment: modified. I hope now it's a bit more clear.

Comment: Ok I solved it - I had to write in Form1:public Object setDataGrid
        {
            set { dataGridView1.DataSource = value; }
        }